# Server-Client Data Exchange using MySQL (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net

Here's the situation. I developed a simple examination system with registration forms. I used VB.Net as the programming language. I haven't tried manual coding for my problem yet.
Anyway this is a project for the company from which I am an intern.

The plan is to get every client pc to have this examination/registration application and this application will send the personal info and the score to a central database(server pc).
I used MySql as the dbms and developed the application on the same machine which means that the Database server I used is only on the local host.

Now I was about to try to implement the application to one client pc(as a beta test) and installed the necessary files(.net framework) and I also installed MySQL Server(and workbench) in the server pc.

When I run the application in the client PC it didn't detect/connect to the ServerPC's MySQL server instance and therefore was not able to record the dummy values I input in the client application. Take note I changed the connection string of my app to point to the ip address of the serverPC.

Now my questions are the following:

1)What have I done wrong?

2)Should I install the MySQL Server(and Workbench) to every ClientPC so that I can create a server instance that uses the REMOTE HOST option and configure it such that it will connect to the SERVERPC's Database?

3)How should I setup the server so it gives access to the application I installed in all clientPCs?

I'm pretty new to VB.net and mostly learned from internet sources. I haven't tried manual coding. Mainly because the tools in VB.net are slightly easy to understand thanks to intellisense,the drag and drop tools and also the help topics.

Anyway I hope anyone helps me. Advance Thanks and If the information i've given is not quite complete please point out to me which info I forgot to add.

EDIT: 
Additional info, the client pcs and the server pc is in one network.
I also granted every privelege to the serverPC settings of MySQL.(it's just for the test run)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you enable the MySQL user for localhost only access?  You can check this in MySQL control center by browsing to your 'mysql' database, 'users' table, am ensure the host field of the user is set to % and not localhost, allowing them to connect on any NIC, not just the loopback (localhost) adapter.

Comment: What do you mean by "MySQL user for localhost only access?"? Do you mean the ServerPC? if that's what you mean then my answer is YES. I've set it up such that it is only for localhost access. by doing this the server will be in the serverPC right?